# express cookie-session failing on mobile

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cookie-session

I am trying to use cookie-session in express / nodejs, my setup works on PCs, but not on mobile:

- on Android/Firefox, I can setup the session cookie, but I cannot modify it once set, I can't event erase it by setting `req.session=null`. Android/chrome is fine.
- on iOS (Safari, chrome, firefox), the cookie doesn't seem to ever be set (iOS 15.3).

The setup is as follows:

- my website is hosted at "mywebsite.com" (names modified for this forum)
- my API setting/using the cookie is at another URL "mywebsite.io" (different extension)

cookie-session options are:

```
name: 'session',
keys: ['my secret'],
sameSite: 'none',
secure: true,
httpOnly: true,
signed: true,
overwrite: true,
```

Both website and API implement https. The API is behind a nginx proxy. Express includes this:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
```

to make sure the secure option works behind the proxy.

The web client is created in React, I run API calls using superagent with the `.withCredentials()` option.

I have tried:

- setting the `maxAge` option
- setting the domain option to 'mywebsite.io' or 'mywebsite.com'
- setting the 'path' option to '/'
- using the should-send-same-site-none module

Whatever I do, the iOS cookie is always empty (req.session = undefined on subsequent calls), and the Android/Firefox combo wont't let me update it.